# Can I make the ocean modifier less repetitive?

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

I have a simple plane with the ocean modifier on it. When I turn the "Repeat X" and "Repeat Y" settings up to make the ocean larger, it just duplicates the same exact pattern out so that my ocean waves are completely tiled. Is there a setting to randomize the ocean waves?
[image: ocean]

Comment: You should not use Repeat to increase the size, it will create repetitions, maybe increase Spatial Size and Resolution as explained here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZfWXvNXp6Q ... If it doesn't work, check Dylan Neill's video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8PSS5HqC-Q

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using *repeat X & Y* use *spatial size* to determine the size of the mesh. The other settings in the modifier are sufficient for some randomization of the generated mesh (time, alignment, etc).

[image]

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/physics/ocean.html#ocean-modifier):

> **Spatial Size**
> The width of the ocean surface area being simulated, in meters. This also determines the size of the generated mesh, or the
> displaced area. Of course, you can scale the object with the Ocean
> modifier in Object Mode to tweak the apparent size in your scene.